# How to Insert a JSON fomat message into gmail using gmail api

Tags: gmail-api, google-schemas

We are able to insert the raw format mails into gmail using gmail API.

We want to insert the JSON format message into gmail. None of the messages.insert() support this.

Is there a way around..?

Google developers of gmail-api, will this be supported in the future updates of api..?

Comment: what do you mean, "insert json"? json as an attachment to an email?

Comment: If we use full in the messages.get() we get the whole e-mail as a JSON file. We need to insert back that JSON file using insert which messages.insert() doesn't support right now.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to insert the JSON file back? JSON is just the response from your request method. If you want to insert the JSON file, you need to upload it as an attachment.

You can not turn some properties of the [messages resource](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/insert) into your request parameters. You have to use the required parameters specified in [this document](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/insert). So, you can only use userId, uploadType and internalDateSource as the parameters for your insert request.